# How can I copy a char from an Structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Hello I´m trying to copy a char from a structure. So I have the structure

```
char Person[50]
typedef struct {
char Name[50] = "Hello";
int Date;
float Times86;
}NewName;
```

How can I copy the Hello out of the structure into a normal char.
If I do

```
Person = NewName.Name
```

The Error`assignment to expression with array type` appears

Comment: `NewName` is typedefined `stuct`.  Please update [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4139593)

Comment: This is not specific to structs. Reduce your example to just two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
NewName newname_var;
memcpy(Person, newname_var.Name, sizeof(newname_var.Name));
```

Answer (score -1):

You created array of chars with Person[50], try changing that into char Person;

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now I have the Error "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"